# Emergence of elastic (as well as plastic) properties of metals

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science, atoms, emergent-properties

Whenever a force is applied on an metal it causes deformation and a stress is generated.

[image: Stress-Strain curve for metals]
 Metals form a lattice which has lower energy than isolated metal atoms (due to the formation of metallic bond) and therefore they are in stable equilibrium. And hence when a force is applied a stress is generated. But what I ain't able to understand is:

- Why does an elastic limit exist, after which metals start to show plastic properties?
- What is happening at the atomic level that causes it?

Comment: Currently I am not sure about classical -mechanics tag so feel free to add appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

It is when the stress is so large the metal ions permanently change some of their surrounding neighbouring ions.
The metal undergoes a deformation which is not reversed by the stress being reduced.